# PROLOG - Variable without warning (No Suppression)

Tags: prolog, singleton

I wanted to figure out the possibility to convert the following statement into terms (**not relations**) but without the warning of *Singleton variables: PERSON* while compiling.

> Alex likes everyone who likes icecreams.

My following logic gets the Singleton Warning which I want it to remove. The code works fine though.

```
likes(alex,likes(Person,icecreams)).
```

Comment: Why does this code "work fine though"?

Comment: When I execute query: likes(alex,likes(magen,icecreams)). It evaluates to true and may be any other name, variable. I assume it's working fine. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: `likes(alex,Person) :- likes(Person,icecreams).` would be more correct to me.

Comment: @Rafalon You are right but I don't want to use Rules. :)

Comment: May I ask why ? Well then your answer is `likes(alex,likes(_,icecreams)).`

Comment: @Rafalon Yes you are right. Already answered by you. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives you the same as your try without the warning :

```
likes(alex,likes(_,icecreams)).
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I wanted.